# Check if List object is Empty or not

Tags: java, list, object, if-statement

I've a `List` of domain class where the domain class variables are null and the `List` returns 1 object. Can anyone help me validate the `List` for `null`. `isEmpty` dosn't seem to work.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DomainClass1 d = new DomainClass1();
    List<DomainClass1> domain = new ArrayList<>();
    d.setTest1(null);
    d.setTest2(null);
    d.setTest3(null);
    d.setTest4(null);
    domain.add(d);
    System.out.println(domain);
    if (domain.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("is empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isEmpty()` will never return `true` because the list is simply not empty- you've added 1 element to it.

Comment: How to validate what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is not the same as *empty*. Your list has the size of 1, meaning that there is 1 object (even if all properties of it are null). If you want to check if all its properties are not null then you can fetch each one and check if it is null or not.

You can have an additional method to determine whether the properties are null of not and then just invoke it. For eg:

```
public class DomainClass1 {
   String str1, str2;

   public boolean isEmpty() {
      if (this.str1 != null && this.str2 != null) {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Now invoke it like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < domain.size(); i++) {
   if (domain.get(i).isEmpty()) {
      // all fields null
   } else {
      // not all are null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
domain.isEmpty()
```

it just verify list isEmpty, it do not verify the d's fields isEmpty, you can add a method in DomainClass1 class just like this

```java
public class DomainClass1 {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;
    private String test4;
    ...
    public boolean isEmpty() {
         if(test1 != null || test2 != null || test3 != null || test4 != null) {
             return false;
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

then you can use d.isEmpty() to replace domain.isEmpty()

Comment: also override hashCode() if you override equals Method.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH why?

Comment: @Ruslan see there is a contract between hashcode and equals method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Comment: @SHAHAKASH thanks, but in OP's example `DomainClass1` is not used in hash-based collections like `HashMap`, `HashSet` etc..

Comment: @Ruslan yeah but he also didn't post DomainClass1 class not sure about he didn't use.